# Firebase unique key is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a unique key from firebase to store some data on firebase real-time database but when i try to print my key it returns always nil

**My database reference:**

```
var ref = Database.database().reference()
```

**My key variable:**

```
var key = ref.key
```

Comment: Well if all you are getting is the base reference, there would be no key. Provide some more info on what you are storing and we can helo you from there.

Comment: @goatofanerd i just want to get a random key from firebase to set the ID of some items inside database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the key of the root node, which is by definition going to be `nil`.

To get a new unique child reference that you can write to, call `childByAutoId()` on the parent reference. For example, to write under a new unique child node under the root, you could do:

```
ref.childByAutoId().setValue("your value")
```

To just get a new unique ID that you can use elsewhere, you can also do:

```
ref.childByAutoId().key
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no key produced for the root reference, add a `.child` and it should work. Otherwise, there is no point in the key as it is the root of the database.

Example:

```
var key = ref.child("Test").key
```

Comment: Now is returns this: `Optional("Test")
`

Comment: That is the expect value @GSepetadelis. Did you expect something else to be returned?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, i just want to get a unique key from firebase to set the ID of some items inside database

Comment: To get a new unique child reference, call `childByAutoId()` on the parent reference. For example, to write under a new unique child node, you could do `ref.childByAutoId().setValue("your value")`